# Visualizing output of convolutional layer in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to visualize the output of a convolutional layer in tensorflow using the function `tf.image_summary`. I'm already using it successfully in other instances (e. g. visualizing the input image), but have some difficulties reshaping the output here correctly. I have the following conv layer:

```py
img_size = 256
x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1,img_size, img_size,1], "sketch_image")

W_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 1, 32])
b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])

h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)
```

So the output of `h_conv1` would have the shape `[-1, img_size, img_size, 32]`. Just using `tf.image_summary("first_conv", tf.reshape(h_conv1, [-1, img_size, img_size, 1]))` Doesn't account for the 32 different kernels, so I'm basically slicing through different feature maps here.

How can I reshape them correctly? Or is there another helper function I could use for including this output in the summary?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I don't know of a helper function but if you want to see all the filters you can pack them into one image with some fancy uses of `tf.transpose`.

So if you have a tensor that's `images` x `ix` x `iy` x `channels`

```py
>>> V = tf.Variable()
>>> print V.get_shape()

TensorShape([Dimension(-1), Dimension(256), Dimension(256), Dimension(32)])
```

So in this example `ix = 256`, `iy=256`, `channels=32`

first slice off 1 image, and remove the `image` dimension

```py
V = tf.slice(V,(0,0,0,0),(1,-1,-1,-1)) #V[0,...]
V = tf.reshape(V,(iy,ix,channels))
```

Next add a couple of pixels of zero padding around the image

```py
ix += 4
iy += 4
V = tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad(image, iy, ix)
```

Then reshape so that instead of 32 channels you have 4x8 channels, lets call them `cy=4` and `cx=8`.

```py
V = tf.reshape(V,(iy,ix,cy,cx))
```

Now the tricky part. `tf` seems to return results in C-order, numpy's default.

The current order, if flattened, would list all the channels for the first pixel (iterating over `cx` and `cy`), before listing the channels of the second pixel (incrementing `ix`). Going across the rows of pixels (`ix`) before incrementing to the next row (`iy`).

We want the order that would lay out the images in a grid.
So you go across a row of an image (`ix`), before stepping along the row of channels (`cx`), when you hit the end of the row of channels you step to the next row in the image (`iy`) and when you run out or rows in the image you increment to the next row of channels (`cy`). so:

```py
V = tf.transpose(V,(2,0,3,1)) #cy,iy,cx,ix
```

Personally I prefer `np.einsum` for fancy transposes, for readability, but it's not in `tf` [yet](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/175).

```py
newtensor = np.einsum('yxYX->YyXx',oldtensor)
```

anyway, now that the pixels are in the right order, we can safely flatten it into a 2d tensor:

```py
# image_summary needs 4d input
V = tf.reshape(V,(1,cy*iy,cx*ix,1))
```

try `tf.image_summary` on that, you should get a grid of little images.

Below is an image of  what one gets after following all the steps here.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was stuck on transpose part. I ended up using a [slightly different version](https://gist.github.com/panmari/4622b78ce21e44e2d69c) since I'm ok with with seeing only the first few convolutions (I don't need all of them assembled in a grid). The grid is kinda hard to inspect on the tensorboard.

Comment: It seems to me that the last fy and fx you wrote are actually cy and cx

Comment: What is more you can only pass 4D tensor to `tf.image_summary` so you will have to reshape `V=tf.reshape(V,(1,4*256,8*256,1))`

Comment: But thanks this use of transpose to swap axes is actually pretty convenient !

Comment: Thanks! they keep getting me with that 4d requirement on things (Batch Norm for example), I've fixed it in the answer.

Comment: @mdaoust Should the line `V = tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad(image, iy, ix)` have V as the first argument instead of image? I can't see where image comes from?

Comment: I guess in this line V = tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad(image, iy, ix) , the "image", should be replaced with V. And something of   tf.summary.image("image_name", V )  would be used for recent version of tensor flow. It actually works well!

Answer (score 2):

In case someone would like to "jump" to numpy and visualize "there" here is an example how to display both `Weights` and `processing result`. All transformations are based on prev answer by `mdaoust`.

```py
# to visualize 1st conv layer Weights
vv1 = sess.run(W_conv1)

# to visualize 1st conv layer output
vv2 = sess.run(h_conv1,feed_dict = {img_ph:x, keep_prob: 1.0})
vv2 = vv2[0,:,:,:]   # in case of bunch out - slice first img


def vis_conv(v,ix,iy,ch,cy,cx, p = 0) :
    v = np.reshape(v,(iy,ix,ch))
    ix += 2
    iy += 2
    npad = ((1,1), (1,1), (0,0))
    v = np.pad(v, pad_width=npad, mode='constant', constant_values=p)
    v = np.reshape(v,(iy,ix,cy,cx)) 
    v = np.transpose(v,(2,0,3,1)) #cy,iy,cx,ix
    v = np.reshape(v,(cy*iy,cx*ix))
    return v

# W_conv1 - weights
ix = 5  # data size
iy = 5
ch = 32   
cy = 4   # grid from channels:  32 = 4x8
cx = 8
v  = vis_conv(vv1,ix,iy,ch,cy,cx)
plt.figure(figsize = (8,8))
plt.imshow(v,cmap="Greys_r",interpolation='nearest')

#  h_conv1 - processed image
ix = 30  # data size
iy = 30
v  = vis_conv(vv2,ix,iy,ch,cy,cx)
plt.figure(figsize = (8,8))
plt.imshow(v,cmap="Greys_r",interpolation='nearest')
```

Answer (score 1):

you may try to get convolution layer activation image this way:

```
    h_conv1_features = tf.unpack(h_conv1, axis=3)
    h_conv1_imgs = tf.expand_dims(tf.concat(1, h_conv1_features_padded), -1)
```

this gets one vertical stripe with all images concatenated vertically.

if you want them padded (in my case of relu activations to pad with white line):

```
    h_conv1_features = tf.unpack(h_conv1, axis=3)
    h_conv1_max = tf.reduce_max(h_conv1)
    h_conv1_features_padded = map(lambda t: tf.pad(t-h_conv1_max, [[0,0],[0,1],[0,0]])+h_conv1_max, h_conv1_features)
    h_conv1_imgs = tf.expand_dims(tf.concat(1, h_conv1_features_padded), -1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally try to tile every 2d-filter in a single image.

For doing this <sub>-if i'm not terribly mistaken since I'm quite new to DL-</sub> I found out that it could be helpful to exploit the [depth_to_space](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/depth_to_space) function, since it takes a 4d tensor

`[batch, height, width, depth]`

and produces an output of shape

`[batch, height*block_size, width*block_size, depth/(block_size*block_size)]`

Where block_size is the number of "tiles" in the output image. The only limitation to this is that the depth should be the square of block_size, which is an integer, otherwise it cannot "fill" the resulting image correctly. 
A possible solution could be of padding the depth of the input tensor up to a depth that is accepted by the method, but I sill havn't tried this.

Answer (score 0):

Another way, which I think very easy, is using the `get_operation_by_name` function. I had hard time visualizing the layers with other methods but this helped me.

```
#first, find out the operations, many of those are micro-operations such as add etc.
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
graph.get_operations()

#choose relevant operations
op_name = '...' 
op = graph.get_operation_by_name(op_name)
out = sess.run([op.outputs[0]], feed_dict={x: img_batch, is_training: False}) 
#img_batch is a single image whose dimensions are (1,n,n,1). 

# out is the output of the layer, do whatever you want with the output
#in my case, I wanted to see the output of a convolution layer
out2 = np.array(out)
print(out2.shape)

# determine, row, col, and fig size etc.
for each_depth in range(out2.shape[4]):
    fig.add_subplot(rows, cols, each_depth+1)
    plt.imshow(out2[0,0,:,:,each_depth], cmap='gray')
```

For example below is the input(colored cat) and output of the second conv layer in my model.[image: below]

Note that I am aware this question is old and there are easier methods with Keras but for people who use an old model from other people (such as me), this may be useful.