# Visualizing the features of a pretrained network in TensorFlow

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow, pre-trained-model

For a medical application I am retraining the pretrained *Inception-v3* network using *TensorFlow*.

This network has a final layer:

> pool_3:0 (2048 features)

Using TF's classify_image, I figured out which of these features are most important for each sample.  So there is an array with the indexes of the top-N features, sorted on weights.

The next step is to **visualize the feature vector** to better understand the results.

How would I go about doing this? Is TensorBoard capable of this?
I am at a bit of a loss. Any suggestion/help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe just printing the N interesting components would help you?

You can get the `pool_3` vector with something like:

```py
graph = ...   # the session graph (sess.graph) containing Inception model
features = graph.get_tensor_by_name('inception_v3/pool3:0')  # I don't know the exact name, find it in TensorBoard
features_values = sess.run(features)
print features_values[top_N_indices]
```

---

If you want to use TensorBoard, you can only plot:

- scalar features (scalar summaries): you could plot each feature independently with this, using `tf.gather(features, [indice])`
- histograms of activation: this will not be very useful I think but you can try it
- images: you could maybe construct an image to plot containing the interesting features? That would be a bit complex, you can see [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33802336/visualizing-output-of-convolutional-layer-in-tensorflow), related to [this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/908) and [this tutorial](http://robromijnders.github.io/tensorflow_basic/)